# awk: why match function print the matched line without mentioning to print it

Tags: awk

I have the below content:

```
NODE_1
port 1
description blah
port 2
description blah blah
NODE_2
port 1
description blah
port 2
description blah
NODE_3
port 1
port 2
NODE_4
port 1
port 2
NODE_5
port 1
port 2
NODE_6
port 1
description blahdy blah
port 2
description floop-a-doop
```

I am trying to print the match properties of first three matches of NODE

```
awk 'BEGIN{count=0}
    match($0,/NODE/,a)
    {
    if(RSTART != 0){
        print "*******************************"
        for (i in a)
        print i"-->"a[i]
        count++;
        print "count-->"count;    
        print "*******************************"
        }
    if (count >= 3)
        {
        exit
        }
    }' awksampledata5.txt
```

The output is

```
NODE_1
*******************************
0start-->1
0length-->4
0-->NODE
count-->1
*******************************
NODE_2
*******************************
0start-->1
0length-->4
0-->NODE
count-->2
*******************************
NODE_3
*******************************
0start-->1
0length-->4
0-->NODE
count-->3
*******************************
```

I dont want NODE_1, NODE_2 and NODE_3 to be printed. But i dont know how its getting printed.

ANSWER EDITED CODE:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{count=0}
        match($0,/NODE/,a){
        if(RSTART != 0){  <-- this matters  new lines matters.
            print "*******************************"
            for (i in a)
            print i"-->"a[i]
            count++;
            print "count-->"count;
            print "*******************************"
            }
        if (count >= 3)
            {
            exit
            }
        }' awksampledata5.txt
*******************************
0start-->1
0length-->4
0-->NODE
count-->1
*******************************
*******************************
0start-->1
0length-->4
0-->NODE
count-->2
*******************************
*******************************
0start-->1
0length-->4
0-->NODE
count-->3
*******************************
```

Comment: wrt `for (i in a)` - there will only ever be 1 thing in `a` and that's `a[0]` which will contain the text `NODE` since that's what you told it to match in `/NODE/`. Not sure what you're trying to do there but try this: `match($0,/(N)(OD)(E)/,a)` and then that loop to see how match() works wrt populating the array. Also - you don't need to test RSTART separately as it'll always be non-zero in that block.

Comment: Thats true i wanted to try for groups also. But this question i want to keep it more for printing the match line, why its happening

Comment: Understood which is why the above is a comment and not part of my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newlines matter. This:

```
match($0,/foo/)
{ bar() }
```

is not the same as either of these:

```
match($0,/foo/) { bar() }

match($0,/foo/) {
    bar()
}
```

The first script says

```
If "foo" exists in $0 then print the current record.
Call bar().
```

while the other 2 say:

```
If "foo" exists in $0 then call bar().
```